# issue with react native local notification and play sound

Tags: react-native, react-native-push-notification, react-native-sound

I'm creating `react native` app on `googleplay` im using react native `pushNotification` and `react-native-sound`
everything is work proper till the last update when I upload bundle on `googleplay` notification sound play with the sound that I use in one of react navigation page old AAB work fine but after updating this issue appears

when I clear data in android , notification sound works fine without any conflict
notification config is in App.js every thing is code proper and responsive

### notification

```
 PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      id: notificationId,
      title: lang.notificationRemaind,
      message: reminder.name, // (required)
      date: new Date(Date.now() + diffSeconds),
      allowWhileIdle: true,
      repeatType: 'week',
      channelId: 'Reminder',
      priority: 'max',
      soundName: 'remind',
    });
```

### sound

```
            try {
                // play the file tone.mp3
                SoundPlayer.playSoundFile('firework', 'mp3')
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(`cannot play the sound file`, e)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I did not use the library for notification sound.

Android:

step1: Add my_sound.mp3 file android/app/src/main/res/raw/my_sound.mp3

step2:

```js
    PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({

      title: lang.notificationRemaind,
      message: reminder.name, 
      playSound: 'true'
      soundName: 'my_sound.mp3',
    });}
```

step3: for local notification add playSound  and SoundName in channel.

```js
PushNotification.createChannel(
        {
            channelId: 'Test',
            channelName: 'test-channel',
            soundName: 'my_sound.mp3'
        }
    )
```

IOS:Add my_sound.mp3 file in xcode as pod level.